# How do i make a discord bot answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot.

I have attached the code below. When I run it there are no errors, the bot says 'Hello, world!', but doesn't answer the 'hi' (as it should answer 'Hello!').

What can I do to make it work?

```
import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
general_channel = client.get_channel('CHANNEL ID')

    await general_channel.send('Hello, world!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == 'hi':
        general_channel = client.get_channel('CHANNEL ID')
        await general_channel.send('Hello!')

client.run ('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that you put `intents=discord.Intents.default()` in your client. This only gives you the default intents, which do not include the `message_content` intent.
You need this intent because you are asking the bot `if message.content == 'hi':`.

First, you need to enable the `message_content` on [your bot](https://discord.com/developers)

After that, type

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents
```

Now if your run the code, it should work.